# robots.txt and relative path

Tags: relative-path, robots.txt

I want to disallow any files in any /tmp folder on my site. e.g. I have: "/anything/tmp/whatever/test.html", "/stuff/tmp/old/test.html", "/people/tmp/images.html", and so on.

Is it enough to put disallow /tmp/ into my robots.txt to block any tmp folder in the whole file system of my webserver? Or do I need to put every single path like: 
disallow /anything/tmp/
disallow /stuff/tmp/
disallow /tmp/

Or like this:
disallow /*/tmp/

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Straight answer: **NO**

You'll have to declare each directory you want to exclude from robots.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /anything/tmp/
Disallow: /stuff/tmp/
```

You can check the syntax of your robots.txt file @ http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check
Read more about Robot Exclusion @ http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the REP parser. More advanced parsers do recognize wildcard syntax, but it's not part of the [original spec](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt).

That said, [Google](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html) does honor wildcards. According to their parser:

```
/fish*.php
Does Match:
    /fish.php 
    /fishheads/catfish.php?parameters
Does Not Match
    /Fish.PHP
```